# How to create tableview with dynamically generated columns of different types?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-2

I am developing a program for accounting attendance of students. I need a table with the first column - a list of students (TableColumn) and the next columns I generate dynamically (list of lectures). At the intersection of a row and column - ComboBox. I found how to make dynamic generation of  of columns for one type (TableView>>), but not found a solution for my case.
I had an idea to create an additional class

```
class Row{
    StringProperty audience;
    ObservableList<Attendence> lectures;
}
```

but do not understand how to implement it.
How to solve this problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is basically the correct one:

```
public class Row{
    private final StringProperty audience = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final List<ObjectProperty<Attendance>> lectures = new ArrayList<>();

    public Row(String audience, int numAttendances) {
        setAudience(audience);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numAttendances ; i++) {
            lectures.add(new SimpleObjectProperty<>());
        }
    }

    public List<ObjectProperty<Attendance>> getLectures() {
        return lectures ;
    }

    public StringProperty audienceProperty() { 
        return audience ;
    }

    public final String getAudience() {
        return audienceProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setAudience(String audience) {
        audienceProperty().set(audience);
    }
}
```

Now you can set your table up as follows:

```
int numLectures = ... ;
TableView<Row> table = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<Row, String> audienceCol = new TableColumn<>("Audience");
audienceCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().audienceProperty());
table.getColumns().add(audienceCol);
for (int i = 0 ; i < numLectures ; i++) {
    TableColumn<Row, Attendance> col = new TableColumn<>("Attendance "+ (i+1));
    final int colIndex = i ;
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getLectures().get(colIndex));
    table.getColumns().add(col);
}
```